# android static library bad ELF number

Tags: android, static, numbers, elf

I have build a static library with the Android ndk.

I now try to use this library in another Android project

```
//in mainActivity
static
{
    System.loadLibrary("MILlib");
}
```

I got the following error when building the test project

> 02 17:07:24.890 2785-2785/com.MIL.testlib E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                  Process: com.MIL.testlib, PID: 2785
>                                                                  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.MIL.testlib-1/lib/arm/libMILlib.so" has bad ELF magic
>                                                                      at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:371)
>                                                                      at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
>                                                                      at com.MIL.testlib.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:112)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1650)
>                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2640)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2873)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1482)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

What is a bad ELF magic number and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 10):

A `.so` object is a shared object file. This is native code as opposed to a Java library and it is called an `ELF` because it is in Extensible Linking Format.

The "magic" refers to the first 64 bits of the `ELF` file. This specifies some header information, including the architecture of the system it was built for.

Android phones support three architectures: ARM, Intel, and MIPS.  Emulators support the hardware they are running on, usually Intel. Given that your `.so` has 'arm' in the directory path, I suspect that your `.so` is an ARM `.so` and you are trying to run this on either Intel or MIPS.