# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: ".../libopenblas.so" has bad ELF magic: 00000000

Tags: java, android, android-studio, static, elf

I'm new in OpenCV and Android. I'm trying to start detecting faces on photo and saving them in a folder in my function `public void findObject(Bitmap selectGallery) throws IOException, URISyntaxException`. But on the first line of this function: `IplImage photo = new IplImage();`it throws exception: 
*java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/~~ACySg1uTUyhppgyWvwgUvQ==/com.example.facerecognition-6eGAFcf-bmpcYcpTJt7J9g==/lib/x86/libjniopenblas_nolapack.so" has bad ELF magic: 00000000

**Caused by**: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/~~ACySg1uTUyhppgyWvwgUvQ==/com.example.facerecognition-6eGAFcf-bmpcYcpTJt7J9g==/lib/x86/libopenblas.so" has bad ELF magic: 00000000*

This method I call from this block:

```
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                    try {
                        proccessHelper.findObject(selectGallery);
                    }catch(URISyntaxException | IOException e){
                        e.getMessage();
                    }
                }
                break;
                default: {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    };
```

And this block is called from:

```
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_6, this, mLoaderCallback);
    }
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595807/android-static-library-bad-elf-number), but it wasn't helpful:( 
I'm working on Windows and found [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c) link, there is an instruction of loading openCV in my project. All .so files in my jniLibs are taken from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/), but there is only one libopencv_java3.so 
Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like `/lib/x86/libopenblas.so` is not a valid ELF file. Running `objdump` on that file may give some insight into what the problem is. My guess is that `/lib/x86/libopenblas.so` is a symlink, and the program is trying to open it instead of following the link. You could check this with `ls -A /lib/x86 | grep libopenblas`.

Comment: So Android and "/lib/x86/"? Do you think that *might* be a problem? Are you on x86_64, x86 or arm? I think you're supposed to use good [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) magic against bad ELF magic. Then again: Good, Bad, Who Can Say? -- Ancient Proverb

Comment: @HackerBoss your commands for linux and I'm using Windows.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm on x86.

Comment: If you're on Windows, why are you trying to use a Linux library? Windows libraries end in `.dll`, and that is some bad ELF magic indeed.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I found this link https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c and there is an instruction of loading openCV in my project. All .so files in my jniLibs, but there is only one libopencv_java3.so

Comment: @shimanovAV If you **edit** you question, ***maybe*** someone will read that blog post, find the error and contact the author. It doesn't seem like a very beginner friendly guide, in fact I would say it isn't helpful. And the time estimate of six minutes appears to be **way** off.

Comment: @shimanovAV I inferred you were on linux because Windows doesn't use ELF file format or shared object files.

Comment: @HackerBoss Windows doesn't [*usually*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WSL) use ELF; but the world has gone mad these days.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Well of course WSL is intended for running linux, but I didn't get the impression that the OP was using WSL.

Comment: @HackerBoss I have no idea what OP is using either, but there is definitely something hokey with that rappers blog post. I read the entirety. I can only hope Elvis is dropping beats.